# How do I input information from a text file to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I had to make an animal class that would allow the user to put in information and print out some text based on that information.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self,species='default',language='default',age=0):
        self.species=species
        self.language=language
        self.age=age
    def setSpecies(self, species):
        #set animal species
        self.species=species
    def setLanguage(self, language):
        #set animal language
        self.language=language    
    def setAge(self, age):
        #set animal age
        self.age=age    
    def speak(self):
        #prints a sentance by the animal
        print('I am a {} year old {} and I {}.'.format(self.age, self.species, self.language))
    def __repr__(self):
        #return string representation
        return "Animal,'{}','{}',{}".format(self.species,self.language,self.age)
    def __eq__(self, new):
        #compares animals
        return self.species==new.species and self.language==new.language and self.age==new.age
```

Now I have to write a function processAnimals() that takes one argument, the name of an input file.   The function returns the list of animals created or an empty list if the file didn't contain any lines. 
The processAnimals() function should read all lines in the file, creating an Animal object for each line and placing the object into a list.

```
def processAnimals(fname):
    with open(fname,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = fname.strip().split(',')         
            print('I am a {} year old {} and i {}.').format(self.species,self.language,self.age)
```

I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'`

when i remove `.format(self.species,self.language,self.age)` it prints

```
I am a {} year old {} and i {}.

I am a {} year old {} and i {}.

I am a {} year old {} and i {}.
```

This is what i need but the `{}` should have information from the file

Text file:

```
cat,meow,8
dog,bark,22
bat,use sonar,2
```

I think my problem might be the reading of the file but I'm not really sure.

Comment: You first have to create the instance of the class animal ,then only you can use methods of that object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- You are iterating over an open file `fname` with `for line in f`.  You are then immediately doing `line = fname.strip().split(',')`, which redefines `line` based on the `fname` - the name of a file.  You want to split `line`, not `fname`.
- You are doing `print('something').format(else)`.  You are calling the `format` method on a `print()` object.  The `print()` function returns nothing, so calling `format` is equivalent to `None.format()`, which obviously won't work.  You want to call `format` on the string, not the `print` function.  So `print('something'.format(else))` rather than `print('something').format(else)`
- You are using `self.species, self.language, self.age` inside `processAnimals`.  Unless the `processAnimals` is a class method of `Animals`, and I'm guessing it isn't since its only argument is `fname`, there is no `self` object to call a method on.  You need to instantiate the `Animals` class for each line before you call a method.

You could do:

```
def processAnimals(fname):
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            new_animal = Animal(*(line.strip().split(',')))
            print('I am a {} year old {} and i {}.'.format(new_animal.species, new_animal.language, new_animal.age))
```

Comment: That has gotten me alot clser thank you. Now it is printing I am a defaul year old default and I 0. I still need it to put the txt file information in though

Comment: Thank you so much it works now, and I understand where I went wrong to, thanks to your wonderful explanations.